# Python string method find() and membership operation (in,not in)?

Tags: python, string

In core python programming,2nd edition.

6.3 Strings and Operators.

"The membership question asks whether a (sub)string appears in a (nother) string. true is returned if that character appears in the string and False otherwise. **Note that the membership operation is not used to determine if a substring is within a string**. Such functionality can be accomplished by using the string methods or string module functions find() or index() (and their brethren rfind() and rindex()).
"

I'm confused by this.So what dose it mean by saying"Note that the membership operation is not used to determine if a substring is within a string." Shouldn't i use in or not in to find out whether a substring is within a string?

Comment: Yet another Python book to add to the burn pile...

Comment: That has to be a typo. The only way that sentence makes sense is if it's supposed to be: "Note that the membership operation is not used to determine **where** a substring is within a string." since `index` and `find` return a location instead of just true/false.

Comment: @tzaman Thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Membership/containment *can* be used to detect presence of a substring within a string. Using it for a single character is simply a degenerate form of substring searching, since a "single character" in Python is a string of length 1.

```
>>> 'foo' in 'foobar'
True
>>> 'fba' in 'foobar'
False
```

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question, how do you think about @tzaman's comment, he point out that this maybe a typo.

Comment: @Kethylar: Correcting that would make the sentence make sense. The previous two sentences also need to be changed, since the first talks about a substring and the second switches to a character.